# Share directories with Active Directory users

Tags: sharing, active-directory, kerberos

I need to configure an Ubuntu, to share directories. The allowed users are in an Active Directory in Windows 2003 server. Can I use ntlm for that or only kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to mount directories from windows domain file server.

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

after code post this

```
//10.0.0.0/path /home/path cifs username=ADusername,password=ADpass 0 0
```